# Error "Cannot find variable `..`" when trying to use range operator

Tags: list, elm

According to much of the [documentation in Elm](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/List) I should be able to use `[1..5]` to get a list of numbers from 1 to 5. But when I try it in `elm-repl`, I'm met with an error:

```
> [1..5]
-- NAMING ERROR ---------------------------------------------- repl-temp-000.elm

Cannot find variable `..`

3|   [1..5]
      ^^^^
```

I tried importing the `List` module as well:

```
> import List exposing (..)
> [1..5]
-- NAMING ERROR ---------------------------------------------- repl-temp-000.elm

Cannot find variable `..`

4|   [1..5]
      ^^^^
```

I know I can use [`List`'s `range` function](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/List#range), but I'm curious to know what I'm doing wrong with the prettier `..` syntax or if that was removed without the documentation being updated?

Comment: Unfortunately, outdated documentation often ranks higher in search results than the current documentation when it comes to Elm. Always be sure to check that you're reading the most current version, especially since there are pretty major differences between each of the last few versions.

Comment: All the current documentation references the `[1..5]` syntax

Comment: Good catch. I'll fix those usages and send in a pull request. I found one on the /docs/syntax page, are there any other examples you can point out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like that documentation is just out of date. The `..` range syntax was removed in v0.18 in favor of the `List.range` function you mention. [Here are the release notes](http://elm-lang.org/blog/the-perfect-bug-report).

> The `[1..5]` syntax was removed in favor of `List.range`. The syntax was kind of nice, but not very discoverable or commonly used. Whenever I used `[1..5]` in a talk, someone quite experienced would comment that they wanted something like that but could not find it in the standard libraries!